# Round float to 2 digits after dot in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm using this code:

```
f = 0.3223322
float('%.2f' % (f))
```

Is there more pythonic, less verbose method without 2 castings?
Using [round](http://The%20behavior%20of%20round()%20for%20floats%20can%20be%20surprising:%20for%20example,%20round(2.675,%202)%20gives%202.67%20instead%20of%20the%20expected%202.68.%20This%20is%20not%20a%20bug:%20it%E2%80%99s%20a%20result%20of%20the%20fact%20that%20most%20decimal%20fractions%20can%E2%80%99t%20be%20represented%20exactly%20as%20a%20float.%20See%20Floating%20Point%20Arithmetic:%20Issues%20and%20Limitations%20for%20more%20information.) is discouraging by the following note from the documentation

> The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for example,
>   round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This is not a
>   bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be
>   represented exactly as a float. See Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues
>   and Limitations for more information.

Comment: Note that `float('%.2f' % f)` has exactly the same issue as `round()`. That's because, as the documentation says, it's a limitation of the way floating points work on computers. I wouldn't worry about it in most situations. In case it does matter, I think it's better to use the `decimal` module, or the `fractions` module, or some arbitary precision library, depending on the exact use case.

Comment: What are you trying to round for?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`round(number[, ndigits])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

```
>>> round(0.3223322, 2)
0.32
```

Note that you’ll probably still want to use a certain precision of string formatting when producing output due to floating point imprecision.

Depending on what you’re trying to achieve, it might be appropriate to use the `Decimal` type:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> round(Decimal(0.3223322), 2)
Decimal('0.32')
```

which does its math in (surprise!) decimal instead of binary and therefore doesn’t suffer any issues with decimal rounding (except initially if you’re trying to create it from a float).

Answer (score 3):

This is not as nice, but I'm always a fan of:

```
f=float(int(100*f))/100
```

Far from the best way to do it, but it's one I use often.

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with good old, built in [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)?

Use it like so:

```
round(input, digits)
```

Example output:

```
>>> f = 0.3223322
>>> round(f, 2)
0.32
```

Comment: In round function if your number after digits upper than 5 return number that greater than of you excepted number
for example: 
round(3.248) => 3.25

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with `round()` but if you don't like its behavior you can always write your own `round()` so, for the sake of completness:

```
def custom_round(number, ndigits=2):
    return int(number * 10 ** ndigits) / 10.0 ** ndigits if ndigits else int(number)
```

Keep in mind that this round, unlike the builtin `round()` rounds down, not up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Decimal with quantize and rounding. ROUND_HALF_UP is a mathematical rounding.

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP

>>> Decimal('123.527').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('123.53')

>>> Decimal('123.525').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('123.53')
```