# Converting from three decimals places to two decimal places in a list

Tags: python, list, decimal

I have a list `online= [204.945, 205.953, 346.457]` and I want to only have the numbers in the list to two decimal places (one list rounded and one list not-rounded). So like this, `online= [204.94, 205.95, 346.45]` for the not rounded and like this `online= [204.95, 205.95, 346.46]` for the rounded.

I don't even know any code that makes this possible, so I don't really have a code to show my approach. I mean I did try to play around with `int()` but that seems to remove all the decimal places and just gives me an integer.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `round` function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round float to 2 digits after dot in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101877/round-float-to-2-digits-after-dot-in-python)

Comment: They're both rounded, just in different directions. (One rounds down, the other towards the nearest hundredths.)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I just got introduced to round functions and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) along with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

```py
list(map(lambda x: round(x,2), online))
```

Or, [List-Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

```py
[round(item,2) for item in online]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[204.94, 205.95, 346.46]
```

Comment: This worked but it seems to round the last digit.  Is there a way to go from lets say `x=[5.67, 6.68]` to `y=[5.6, 6.6]` without any rounding.

Comment: @Zegary That's called Truncation not rounding, You can take a look at [How to truncate float values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/how-to-truncate-float-values)

Answer (score 0):

Following function will do that:

```
def to_2_decimals(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i]=int(l[i]*100)/100

online= [204.945, 205.953, 346.457,0.0147932132,142314324.342545]
to_2_decimals(online)
print(online)
```

But know, that rounding doubles does not save memory. If you just want string representation of your list elements to be shorter then use:

```
print("{:.2f}".format(online[i]))
```