# Rounding float number to the nearest tenth

Tags: python

Hi i have a number like 1.3333333333(THE RESULT OF PYTHON DIVISION) to round of to the nearest tenth

**Input**

> 1.333333333

**Output**

> 1.34 or 1.3

Here is what i tried

```
    def round(self,oj):
        try:
            (bd,ad) = oj.split(".")
            if int(ad[1]) >5:
                up = True   
            else:
                up= False
            if up:
                if ad[0]==9:
                    oj = str(int(bd)+1)
                
                else:
                    oj = str(bd)+"."+str(int(ad[0])+1)
            else:
                oj =str( bd)+"."+ad[0]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        
        return float(oj)
```

But i believe there is a better way to do it so please tell any suggestions you have

Comment: If there is a module please tell is also

Comment: Checkout [round function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round).

Comment: Your function definition overwrites the default python function `round()`. Note that in Python 2, this used to be kind of a rounding up function, but in Python 3, it now rounds to nearest even number. `round(value, 1)` rounds to the nearest even tenth.

Comment: Yes thanks for letting me know ☺️

Comment: If you only want to **round it for display purposes**, f-strings: `f'{x:.1f}'` will give `'0.3'`, or other formatting mthods. Or do you actually want to get the numerical value rounded to a tenth, to use in further calculations?

Comment: Near-duplicate: [Round float to 2 digits after dot in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101877/round-float-to-2-digits-after-dot-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can round the number in python.

#### 1) Use the `round()` function.

```
round(1.33333, 1) #return float
```

Output: 1.3

#### 2) Use the `format()` function.

```
"{0:.1f}".format(1.33333) #return string
```

Output: 1.3

#### 3) Use a format-string with the "%" operator

```
"%.1f" % 1.333333 #return string
```

Output: 1.3